# R: check if column values decrease / increase

Tags: r

```
> dput(subset)
structure(list(MEMORY1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), MEMORY2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MEMORY3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MEMORY4 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), MEMORY5 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), MEMORY6 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), MEMORY7 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), MEMORY8 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("MEMORY1", "MEMORY2", "MEMORY3", 
"MEMORY4", "MEMORY5", "MEMORY6", "MEMORY7", "MEMORY8"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

> subset
  MEMORY1 MEMORY2 MEMORY3 MEMORY4 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 MEMORY8
1       1       1       1       2       1       1       2       1
2       1       1       2       2       2       1       2       1
3       1       1       1       2       1       2       2       1
4       1       1       1       2       2       1       2       1
5       2       1       1       2       1       2       1       1

reversion = vector()
#initialize vector
for(i in 1:ncol(subset)){
   if(all(diff(subset[[index]]) < 0)){
      ... #append column number to reversion
   }else reversion = reversion
}
```

For each column in `subset`, I want to check whether or not there is a reversion (i.e, the value decreases as I move down the rows). So for instance, MEMORY1 has no reversions, neither does MEMORY2. But MEMORY3 does. I'm trying to write a loop that outputs a vector `reversion` that contains the column numbers of the columns that have reversions. In this case I want my `reversion` vector to contain `3 5 6 7` since those are the columns with reversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `diff` function returns the differences between consecutive pairs of elements in a vector, and you can check if any of those values are negative with `any`. All that remains is to apply this to the columns of your data frame with `sapply` and grab the indicated column numbers with `which`.

You can put this all together into a one-liner to grab the required column numbers:

```
which(sapply(subset, function(x) any(diff(x) < 0)))
# MEMORY3 MEMORY5 MEMORY6 MEMORY7 
#       3       5       6       7
```

If you instead wanted to unnamed vector, you could use `unname`:

```
unname(which(sapply(subset, function(x) any(diff(x) < 0))))
# [1] 3 5 6 7
```

Note that I avoided appending matching indices in a loop by computing a logical vector of whether each column fit the criterion and then using `which` on that vector. In general this will keep your code cleaner and may help you avoid some inefficiencies from growing objects one at a time (for details, check out the second circle of [the R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).